# sklearn mixture.GMM in python using univariate GMM

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, gmm, mclust

In R, mclust has an argument 'modelNames' where you can define which model to implement. I wish to do a univariate modeling which is also `modelNames <- 'V'` in mclust under mixture.GMM in python. However, the only thing I find that I can tweak with is the covariance_type. Nonetheless, when I run the same data using R and `mixture.GMM` under `sklearn`, I get different fitting despite the same number of fitted components. What could I change in `mixture.GMM` to indicate I am using a univariate variable variance?

mclust code:

```
function(x){Mclust(ma78[x,],G=2,modelNames="V",verbose=FALSE)}
```

GMM code:

```
gmm = GMM(n_components = 2).fit(data)
```

Comment: You should post the code you are using. It would be easy to understand that way.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I don't know if this would help. Thank you! Mainly the issue is I do not know what to do under mixture.GMM to make sure it is fitting a univariate model not a multivariate.

Answer (score 0):

With univariate data, the covariance can either be equal or unique (variable). With `Mclust` these options are `modelNames = "E"` or `"V"`, respectively.

With `sklearn`, they appear to be `covariance_type = "tied"` or `"full"`. Possibly, something like this for variable Gaussian mixture model

```
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components = 2, covariance_type='full').fit(data)
```

Even using `Mclust` or `sklearn` alone there can be instanced that you may not get same parameter values for different runs - this is because the estimates can depend on the initial values. One way to avoid this is using a larger number of starts if such option is available.

Comment: Thank you. I like to point out that I solved partially the problem by changing the argument 'tol' to 1e-5 instead of the default 1e-3 which is what the tol is set as for mclust getting me a closer result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499130/fitting-mixture-model-of-gaussians-and-uniform-distributions-to-real-data). The only thing you have to do is to reshape your data `data.reshape(-1, 1)` before you pass it into `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture`

Andreas